# I want to copy, paste and cut content in my CEdit from my Clipboard

Tags: user-interface, visual-c++, mfc

This is the event handlers i implemented to the copy, paste and Cut buttons in my `MFCRibbonBar`:

in the `MyRibbonView.cpp`:

```
void CMyRibbonView::OnEditCopy()
{
    CWnd *wnd = GetFocus();
    if (wnd == pEdit)
        pEdit->Copy();
    if (!OpenClipboard())
    {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Cannot open the Clipboard"));
        return;
    }
    if (!EmptyClipboard())
    {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Cannot empty the Clipboard"));
        return;
    }
    HGLOBAL hGlob = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, 64);
    strcpy_s((char*)hGlob, 64, "Current selection\r\n");
    if (::SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hGlob) == NULL)
    {
        CString msg;
        msg.Format(_T("Unable to set Clipboard data, error: %d"), GetLastError());
        AfxMessageBox(msg);
        CloseClipboard();
        GlobalFree(hGlob);
        return;
    }
    CloseClipboard();
}
void CMyRibbonView::OnEditPaste()
{
    if (OpenClipboard())
    {
        HANDLE hClipboardData = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);
        char *pchData = (char*)GlobalLock(hClipboardData);
        CString strFromClipboard;
        strFromClipboard = pchData;
        pEdit->SetWindowText(strFromClipboard);
        GlobalUnlock(hClipboardData);
        CloseClipboard();
    }
}
void CMyRibbonView::OnEditCut()
{
    OnEditCopy();
    pEdit->SetWindowText(L" ");
}
```

There is no errors, it's just not working. I tested it by adding the messages to check if it's actually the data or not but they're not popping up.

Comment: Don't quite understand. I think ALL edit-boxes do support cut, copy, paste, select all etc etc operations. And wizard-generated code already contains menu-items and toolbar buttons linked to the `CEditView`-derived class operations, properly enabled/disabled when text gets selected or unselected. Why is this needed at all?

Comment: i want to be able to copy, paste and cut from my ribbon bar. But also using shortcuts for that didn't work with the CEdit.

Comment: Even so, why not just tell the `CEdit` (or what is) to copy its contents to the Clipboard instead? You call `pEdit->Copy()`, but only if it focused. Then you try (again) to copy its contents to the Clipboard yourself. Quite strange. What does your code try to do, other than `pEdit->Copy()`? Doesn't it do the same thing? It's rather a matter of UI design, you need to decide what the operations will be doing, from which UI items should be able to be called and under which conditions.

Comment: Again, `CEditView`-derived views do this on their own. For example, the copy button in the toolbar (and I guess in the ribbon bar as well) will be enabled when some text in the Edit-View is selected. And when clicked copies the selected text to the Clipboard.

Comment: Have you put breakpoints to confirm that your hotkeys are being intercepted?

Comment: I tried adding `pEdit->Cut();`, `pEdit->Copy();` and `pEdit->Paste();`on their own and that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `GlobalLock` your `hGlob` memory before copying your character string into it (this operation converts it into a usable pointer for your process - [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-globallock)), and then call `GlobalUnlock` after you've done that (so that the clipboard can access `hGlob`):

```cpp
HGLOBAL hGlob = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, 64); // Maybe also need GMEM_MOVEABLE here instead?
char* cCopy = (char*)GlobalLock(hGlob);
strcpy_s(cGlob, 64, "Current selection\r\n");
GlobalUnlock(hGlob); 
if (::SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hGlob) == NULL)
{
    //...
```

And you'll need a similar arrangement for the paste operation.

Comment: @NajatIsmail Can you put a `Beep()` (or something) in your Copy/Paste/Cut handlers, just to make sure they are actually being called?

Comment: I added a `MessageBox`, they are being called.